# mocking boto3 client for exceptions

Tags: python-3.x, pytest, pytest-mock, magicmock

I have successfully mocked boto3 client to test the positive case but unable to mock the same client for exceptions here is the code that i tried to mock the get_secret_value method of boto3 client to raise a ClientError.

```
class SecretsManager:

def __init__(self):
    self.session = boto3.session.Session()
    self.client = self.session.client(service_name='secretsmanager', region_name='region-name')
    self.get_secrets()

def get_secrets(self):  # no-pragma

    try:
        get_secret_value_response = self.client.get_secret_value(
            SecretId=self.secret_name)
    except ClientError as e:
        if e.response['Error']['Code'] == 'DecryptionFailureException':
            raise e
        
    else:
        if 'SecretString' in get_secret_value_response:
            secret = get_secret_value_response['SecretString']
            self.secrets_dict = json.loads(secret)
        else:
            decoded_binary_secret = base64.b64decode(
                get_secret_value_response['SecretBinary'])
```

Tests:

```
class TestSecretsManager:

@mock.patch("boto3.session.Session")
def test_get_secrets(self, mock_session):
    # Arrange
    mock_session_object = mock.Mock()
    mock_client = mock.Mock()
    mock_client.get_secret_value.return_value = {"SecretString": '{"my-secret1": "val1"}'}
    mock_session_object.client.return_value = mock_client
    mock_session.return_value = mock_session_object

    secrets = SecretsManager()
    assert secrets is not None
    assert len(secrets.secrets_dict) == 1
    assert secrets.secrets_dict['my-secret1'] == 'val1'

@mock.patch("boto3.session.Session")
def test_get_secrets_exception(self, mock_session):
    # Arrange
    mock_session.client.get_secret_value.side_effect = ClientError(error_response={"Error": {"Code": "DecryptionFailureException"}}, operation_name='Test')
    with pytest.raises(Exception) as err:
        secrets = SecretsManager()
    assert err['Error']['Code'] == 'DecryptionFailureException'
```

test 1 is passing but, test 2 is not raising ClientError. Can somebody help me where am going wrong?

Comment: it would be significantly easier if you passed in these objects instead of instantiating the objects in the `__init__` method